# Pulling the database off a Blackberry emulator

Tags: sqlite, blackberry-webworks, cordova-2.0.0

I tried googling it, I tried looking through the simulator directory, but I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know how to pull the sqlite databases off the blackberry emulator? Specifically, I am using Blackberry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5, and simpack 7.0.0.318. I  ask because it would be far easier to manually pull it off, and inspect it than to write select statements for everything.

With Android, its no problem, just go in through DDMS, but I can't figure out blackberry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using WebWorks, why not leverage Ripple with Web Inspector (or just Web Inspector)? You can view the contents of your SQLite database right in the browser:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_webinsp_microsite_1987477_11.html

If you're heart is set on the simulator, this may help:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/41571/666667.jsp

Comment: While I could not get it off of the simulator, I did just end up using persistence.js for database management -- which allowed me to inspect in chrome as well as what you suggested, Ripple, and it also made the application more portable.

Comment: I can't find where to manipulate the sqllite database inside ripple. It seems like ripple uses a *different* sqlite database than chrome uses without ripple, so I don't even know where to find the file to manipulate it with an external tool. Do you have any info on that?

Answer (score 0):

I found my created database in the path `/Device/BlackBerry/system/appdata/rim/webstorage/(application name)` using File explorer in the simulator then copied it to sdcard (which is mounted to a folder in my computer). I can then get the database out from that folder. I use this method to transfer files in and out from the simulator.